# Facebook Like Button - UN AUTHENTIC APP KEY

Tags: facebook, wordpress

I have used the facebook like button for over a year now with no problem.

Recently after i changed some themes on my wordpress page i noticed that the like button was, visible, but no longer working, ie not counting and not linking back to facebook.

I started from scratch and made a new facebook App, with the new ID key for my website.

I entered all the details into the 'facebook like' plugin on wordpress as i had in the past.

This is not working and when i go to facebook debug utility and enter my URL in :

www.clubmelb.com

i receive this error :

App ID does not match domain

The app ID specified within the "fb:app_id" meta tag is not allowed on this domain. You must setup the Connect Base Domains for your app to be a prefix of http://www.clubmelb.com/wordpress.

i do not have the original app id for my website when it used to work, and was wondering if its even possible to just scap an old ID and start a new app linking to that website, or if u can only have the one APP ID per website.

MORE INFO:

Debug

Fetched URL

clubmelb

Data Source

Data Source

Data Source

Data Source

Data Source

Extracted 1 values from : http://www.clubmelb.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/cmlogo2.jpg

Data Source

Data Source

Data Source

"http://clubmelb.com/" extracted from Our normalised version of the url

HELP ME GET MY LIKE BUTTONS BACK UP AND RUNNING PLEASE!

Answer (score 0):

Create a new Facebook App ID with this url: http://www.clubmelb.com/wordpress and use that instead.